# Used Xbox 360 won't turn on anymore

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

My son was given an Xbox 360 by a friend. They claimed it worked fine.  However, when we got it all hooked up it only worked fine for a little while.   Now we turn the power on and you can hear the machine trying to boot up but nothing at all comes on the screen.

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: It may be possible to fix it, but I highly doubt anyone can answer this question w/out physically inspecting your 360.

Comment: Do you have any other information that might help us determine the problem?

Answer (score 4):

When the Xbox 360 starts up, there's a little ring of lights around the power button - are these lights all off, some green, or are any of them red?

If there are green lights, I'd check the connection between the Xbox 360 and the TV, for a start.  The TV probably needs to be on a specific input, depending on how the two devices are connected.  You might also try a different cable or a different input on your TV, if you have multiple inputs that could support the Xbox.  Some Xbox 360s support HDMI, which is probably the best way to go.  There's also a cable that generally comes with them that can be used for either "component" or "composite" inputs on your TV.

If the lights aren't coming on, it might be a power issue, so check the connection to the power supply.  However, you mention it sounds like there is activity, so this seems unlikely.

If the lights are red, there's not much that can be done.  Unfortunately, there's not really any "user serviceable" parts inside an Xbox 360.  It's likely that the box is out of warranty, so Microsoft would probably want to charge you more than it's worth to fix it, but [contacting their support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/browse) might be worth a shot anyhow.

Comment: Perfect except for the red lights... have a scout around the internet for RROD fixes, there are a lot of good guides and I have done it myself.

Comment: I'm always inclined to err on the side of caution and tell people to contact support rather than crack open their consoles.  I'd hate to have someone damage their hardware or void their warranty on my advice.

Comment: totally, but if the xbox is out of warranty you have nothing to lose in trying a repair, other than a couple of £/$/€s on some bolts/thermal paste

Comment: Won't be sending it to Microsoft after that though, Modification.